# Working with a jQuery Slideshow

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to implement a jQuery Slideshow that fades each image in and out and there are controls to scroll to the next or previous image. I'm working off [this](http://www.webchiefdesign.co.uk/blog/simple-jquery-slideshow/index.php) tutorial right now and I was wondering how I'd go about appending each image to the end of the slideshow so when the slideshow reaches the end it doesn't scroll all the way back to the first image but it just continuously goes though them.

Thanks in advance!

Sean

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do you want to fade the images or do you want them to scroll when you click "Next/Previous"?

Comment: If it's just looping the images when they scroll, you can take a look at: http://www.queness.com/post/923/create-a-simple-infinite-carousel-with-jquery or http://bxslider.com/

Comment: Well, I want them to fade in and out as opposed to scrolling but what I'm really interested in is getting the slideshow to continuously go  through the images rather than reaching the end and scrolling right to the beginning. Thanks for the links, I will check the first one out.

Comment: Well if you just want a slideshow that fades in and out images (and loops when it hits the end) there are hundreds of jQuery plugins that do that. One that I find very useful is nivoSlider (http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/) but it's a bit heavy especially if you just want to fadein and out some image.

Other than that, you can follow this simple tutorial: http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

```
$('#previous').click(function() {
                    $('#slideshow img:first').fadeOut(1000).prev().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('#slideshow');
                });

                $('#next').click(function() {
                    $('#slideshow img:first').fadeOut(1000).next().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('#slideshow');
                });
```